# Merge a single list of dictionaries with the same key value

Tags: python

I can see many similar questions on here but not one that I can find that helps me get the desired output.

I have a single list of dictionaries that have the same ID but with different key value pairs, id like to join all those key values pairs into a single list entry, below is a sample of data and the desired output.

Thanks for your help

```
data = [
    {'id': '10', 'animal' : 'cat'},
    {'id': '11', 'animal' : 'dog'},
    {'id': '3', 'animal' : 'pigeon'},
    {'id': '10', 'color' : 'yellow'},
    {'id': '11', 'color' : 'brown'},
    {'id': '3', 'color' : 'grey'},
    {'id': '10', 'type' : 'furry'},
    {'id': '11', 'type' : 'fluffy'},
    {'id': '3', 'type' : 'dirty'},
]
```

desired output

```
data = [
    {'id': '10', 'animal' : 'cat', 'color' : 'yellow', 'type' : 'furry'},
    {'id': '11', 'animal' : 'dog', 'color' : 'brown', 'type' : 'fluffy'},
    {'id': '3', 'animal' : 'pigeon', 'color' : 'grey', 'type' : 'dirty'},
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, one of which is `defaultdict`:

```py
In [1]: data = [
   ...:     {'id': '10', 'animal' : 'cat'},
   ...:     {'id': '11', 'animal' : 'dog'},
   ...:     {'id': '3', 'animal' : 'pigeon'},
   ...:     {'id': '10', 'color' : 'yellow'},
   ...:     {'id': '11', 'color' : 'brown'},
   ...:     {'id': '3', 'color' : 'grey'},
   ...:     {'id': '10', 'type' : 'furry'},
   ...:     {'id': '11', 'type' : 'fluffy'},
   ...:     {'id': '3', 'type' : 'dirty'},
   ...: ]

In [2]: from collections import defaultdict
   ...: ids = defaultdict(dict)
   ...: for d in data:
   ...:     ids[d["id"]].update(d)
   ...:


In [6]: list(ids.values())
Out[6]:
[{'id': '10', 'animal': 'cat', 'color': 'yellow', 'type': 'furry'},
 {'id': '11', 'animal': 'dog', 'color': 'brown', 'type': 'fluffy'},
 {'id': '3', 'animal': 'pigeon', 'color': 'grey', 'type': 'dirty'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `groupby` and `ChainMap`

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import ChainMap

id_getter = lambda x: x['id']
gp = groupby(sorted(data, key=id_getter), key=id_getter)
result = [dict(ChainMap(*a)) for _, a in gp]
```

`groupby` works on sorted collection, hence sort `data` before call `groupby`
`ChainMap` is used to merge a list of dictionaries to a single dictionary

Comment: I think I am incapable of remembering that `ChainMap` exists. I'm always (delightfully) surprised when someone posts an answer that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.9 (ETA Fall 2020), you'll be able to use the `|` operator to merge `dict`s with the same `id` key.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import or_, itemgetter
from functools import reduce

# I know *why* groupby doesn't have an option to
# sort your data first, but that doesn't mean I can't
# wish that it could...
def group(data, key):
    "Iterate over groups of dicts considered equal according to key"
    yield from map(itemgetter(1), groupby(sorted(data, key=key), key))

data = [
    {'id': '10', 'animal' : 'cat'},
    {'id': '11', 'animal' : 'dog'},
    {'id': '3', 'animal' : 'pigeon'},
    {'id': '10', 'color' : 'yellow'},
    {'id': '11', 'color' : 'brown'},
    {'id': '3', 'color' : 'grey'},
    {'id': '10', 'type' : 'furry'},
    {'id': '11', 'type' : 'fluffy'},
    {'id': '3', 'type' : 'dirty'},
    ]


# E.g., {'id': 10, 'animal': 'cat'} | {'id': 10, 'color': 'yellow'}
#  == {'id': 10, 'animal': 'cat', 'color': 'yellow'}
data = [reduce(or_, ds) for ds in group(data, itemgetter('id'))]
```